# How are people safely allowed to fly around in unregistered, armed, warp-capable, and shielded Kaplan F-17 speed freighters?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-picard

La Sirena, a Kaplan F-17 Speed Freighter, piloted by Cristobal Rios, and first introduced in *Star Trek: Picard,* was described as "an unregistered, warp-capable" starship, according to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/La_Sirena).

Chris, or "Rios," as the crew would call him, is a good, responsible, well-trained pilot. It makes sense that he owns a ship, and he deserves one. However, does it make sense to *own a warp-capable **starship** without **registration?***

It might be possible in a future where starships are as common as cars in our current times--but this isn't just some normal cargo freighter.

First of all, Kaplan F-17s are warp-capable.

If you have a criminal with an unregistered, high-tech, high-velocity, warp-capable ship, it's going to be mighty difficult catching that criminal. They could land, terrorize some planet community, and warp off again.

Second of all, Kaplan F-17s are highly maneuverable.

We see La Sirena dodging the fire of the upgraded Romulan Bird of Prey in *PIC: "Absolute Candor,"* and the Bird of Prey missed often enough for La Sirena's shields to stay up the whole time. We also see La Sirena doing high-speed flips, rolls, and other maneuvers. That makes it a formidable opponent.

Third, Kaplan F-17s re well-shielded and have a phaser.

So, not only does La Sirena have advanced propulsion systems and decent shielding systems, but it has a powerful, subatomic level vaporizing phaser.

Phasers, as we know, are extremely powerful, and even hand-held ones can be really destructive. But La Sirena, even thought it might be small, has a **ship-mounted phaser** that could obviously disintegrate the majority of un-shielded settlements/colonies/cities/ships. Not having someone register a ship with a *phaser* seems idiotic to me.

[Ex Astris Scientia](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/), run by Bernd Schneider, with its newly-updated starship database, has [covered this in its description](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/other_ships.htm) and makes a good speculation;

> La Sirena is an unregistered ship, probably unlike other freighters of this type. It doesn't become clear what exactly that means in the late 24th century. Rather than being illegal in the Federation, Rios's ship may be unaffiliated and may acquire licenses to operate on a case-by-case basis, rather than under a permanent contract.

Oh, really? Unregistered with the Federation? A starship with ***advanced propulsion, advanced shielding technology and a 24th century phaser??*** Okay. Well, let's just hope that it's not an inhumane, or rather "inhumanoid" person piloting a Kaplan F-17, rendering resistance highly futile.

So what does "unregistered" mean, and how does this registration, or licensing system work?

Comment: If you have a criminal with a registered, high-tech, high-velocity, warp-capable ship, it's going to be mighty difficult catching that criminal. The most you could do was alert people to the presence of such a ship, but if defenses can detect its existence, the solution, whether registered or unregistered, is a fake registration, or jamming the defenses.

Comment: Hmm. Answers are slow coming in...

Comment: The fundamental misconception here is the assumption that the Federation has any way to prevent it

Comment: Being maneuverable has no tactical advantage in space warfare.  Space is very, very big, and very, very transparent.  In TOS spaceships fired at distances of tens or hundreds of thousands of kilometers and often destroyed their enemies with a single shot. It wasn't until the space battles in DS9 that spaceships got really close in battles, no doubt due to having super advance force shields that a ship had to get really close to have a chance to penetrate.

Comment: @M.A.Golding If there was no tactical advantage to maneuverability in space warfare, there is no _Defiant_, or Peregrine fighters, or fighters in Star Wars.

Comment: @M.A.Golding La Sirena managed to dodge some of the Romulan Bird of Prey's shots because its maneuverability. Well, since maneuverability is useless, we should just get rid of Speed Freighters and Defiant class warships and evasive maneuvers and all that, because if the ship's not big and powerful enough, the Federation doesn't care because it's just going to get destroyed anyways. So saying that maneuverability is useless is just not true.

Comment: Considering that [the historical context](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/registration-merchant-ships/) for Ship Registration was about making sure that Ships were built and Crews were hired in *your* country, or that Cargo & Goods came in either on your ships or ships of the country of origin (i.e. [a Protectionist policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectionism)), why would a post-scarcity interstellar civilisation (such as the Federation) require such a thing?  Perhaps registering is now *optional*, rather than *mandatory*?

Comment: This is asking for a lot of well thought out detail from a show that forgot that Romulans had an entire empire instead of just one planet, that Seven of Nine was a brilliant scientist, that Picard had in fact been a father, and that it was Geordi that Data was close to, not Picard.

Comment: The political situation inside the Federation makes this inevitable.  Planetary membership in the Federation isn't compulsory even for warp-capable species, and the residents of Federation planets are not forcibly held on their planets Berlin-Wall style.  If a Federation citizen travels to a non-Federation planet and acquires a warp-capable ship, what is the Federation *supposed* to do about that? (Edited to add: the Federation's hands-off approach allows for exactly the "warp-capable criminal" scenario OP envisions, as "Devil's Due" demonstrates.)

Comment: For that matter, is it really a great idea to let borgs and Qs and daleks run  around wreaking havoc?

Comment: @user14111 I wasn't aware that Q is a ship made by the Federation.

Comment: And I wasn't aware the Borg Queen worked for the Federation.

Comment: Of course not. Is that a good reason to let them run wild and cause trouble?

Comment: @Harabeck By "been a father", are you referring to "The Inner Light", or "Star Trek: Generations"?  I don't recall him having any children outside that; being a father-*figure*, sure.  He's been tricked into *thinking* someone was his child, and he's been cloned, but I can't remember him having any *actual* children (In fact, I thought this was explicitly a plot-point in both the episode "Family", and the film "Generations"?)

Comment: So maybe the phaser is "aftermarket", and it's just not registered as a Federation civilian vessel. Not all cars that exist are "registered" in their respective residences. Besides, Rios is ex-Starfleet, hardly an "enemy agent".

Comment: @Chronocidal He thought he was a father, he knows what it means to be one. That's what's relevant to scene in Picard where it was brought up. If the writers knew what they were doing, they could have leveraged that to explain why he got involved with a random orphan in the first place, instead of driving it the opposite direction; that he has no idea what being a father is.

Comment: @user14111 Exactly. My point is that the Federation would have control over those small ships;

Comment: @SovereignInquiry To have that level of control, the Federation would have to directly supervise member planets' political and economic systems, and intervene in them when necessary.  In addition, if it encountered any non-member species within its territory, it would have to bar that species from acquiring warp technology.  All first contact episodes would consist of announcing to the new species, "Until we let you join the Federation, you are quarantined to your own system."  A Federation that has a monopoly on armed ships isn't the Federation as it exists on the show.

Comment: This is like the problem of "won't he steal that ship?" from Larry Niven's [Neutron Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_Star_(short_story)). To solution to keep Beowulf Shaeffer from absconding with the _Skydiver_ and sell it or set up a Pirate Business was to hide a bomb on the ship. _"Ausfaller informs Shaeffer that if he does not attempt the mission he will be sent to debtors prison, and that if he attempts to escape in the ship the bomb will be detonated within a week – well before he could even reach another planet, let alone find a buyer for the ship."_

Comment: @M.A.Golding: When your maneuver speed outpaces the gun's (and gunner's, in case of manual aim) tracking speed, maneuverability does matter. Similarly, even for a gun with no tracking latency, the time a projectile takes to hit gives you time to dodge as well. However, for _large_ ships, it's generally easy to tank than it is to dodge (from an engineering perspective). La Sirena is significantly smaller than your average Star Trek main protagonist ship and it will be able to leverage its agility much more.

Comment: This is what happens when writers forget that they aren't writing for Star Wars.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation Well, who has remembered? ',:-|

Comment: Although, you do need some action in any science fiction franchise if it's going to succeed.